# Get user info from mysql database

Tags: php, function, session, authentication

i am making my own php game. So far i have made almost everything. Now to finish it, i need to get id from user who is logged in. I'm not so familiar with the functions and sessions. Please help.
This is what i made so far:
In my index page people login. then they are redirected to this. 
So $_POST['username'] is where user type his user name in index.

```
    <?php

$username = $_POST['username'];

include("Files/config.php");
$connect = @mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if($connect) {
if(mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)) {
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username`='$username'") or   die(mysql_error());
$gatherinfo = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
global $getid;
$getid = $gatherinfo['id'];
echo $getid;

function getuid() {
$_SESSION['getuid'] = $getid;
echo $getid;
}

}
}
else{ echo "Can not connect";}

?>
```

I searched other scripts for this, i found on one it says just $session->uid and it shows his id from mysql.

In mysql database i have table users with info about them

Id, username, password (password is hashed), email,...
Please help me if you can :D

Comment: where have u called the getuid() ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: And why you are not using [Models](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)? You also should use id not username. Usename may change but not id.

Comment: @shin, why would you link newbie to one of worst frameworks in php ?

Comment: @tereško I beg your pardon. I misunderstood that he was using CI.

Comment: how to use getuid() i only know about getmyuid() but this one only gives id teporerly  when user opens the site second time it give another id. So i can't load his info from mysql.

i need to load his mysql info from table so i can make other functions, i don't know what pdo is.

Comment: I'm sorry for possible language mistakes, I'm not english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of index file (where your user logging in) start named session (be careful to avoid echo or print any values before session_start:

```
<?php //index.php
session_name('SAMPLESESSION');
session_start();
```

then when you will get the logged User ID, write this value to the session variable, like this:

```
.....
$_SESSION['uid'] = $getid;
.....
```

in the script you was redirected by your index file start session with the same name and get your user ID:

```
<?php //redirectedfromindex.php
session_name('SAMPLESESSION');
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['uid'];
....
```

If I right understand you, these that you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, i want to give you reputation+ but i can't i don't have enough to do that. Thank you again.